# How to simulate a 'heavy' query in Cassandra?

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

I am writing an integration test for a part of my application and I want to test that my custom `readTimeoutMillis` property is set and works as expected.

In order to do so, I want to simulate a heavy query, which takes more time than `readTimeoutMillis`, but I don't want to use external tools like scassandra or cassandra-stress.

In Java, I would use something like `Thread.sleep(N)` to simulate such behaviour, but I cannot find a way to do this with just CQL.

Comment: Possibly run a query of a few (or several, if necessary) comma separated tables in the from clause withOUT any join conditions or a where clause. The idea is that if the tables have enough rows, the cross product of the running query will exceed the timeout. I'm not familiar with Cassandra, but some other DBs have a sleep() that can be used in a similar way as the thread sleep.

Comment: @PaulT. as far as I understand, there is no sleep() function alternative in Cassandra

Comment: Select count(*) on a large enough table.